# Placeholder value not showing in chrome?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code. I don't understand why placeholder not shown in explorer. Please help.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form  method="post" >
  <input type="text" class="field" name="nom" placeholder="Votre Nom">
  <input type="text" class="field" name="telephone" placeholder="Téléphone">
  <center><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Valider" class="btn_submit"></center>
</form>
```

Comment: Which version of chrome? Its working for me on Version 39.0.2171.71 http://jsfiddle.net/zj0xbe1p/

Comment: It is also working for me in Version 36.0.1985.143 m http://jsfiddle.net/8hqkuyup/

Comment: my google chrome version is Version 39.0.2171.71 m

Comment: @RusselMonzur: it should work. Please try my below mentioned answer, it will definetly work

Comment: i think there is a problem with my css . can you what css can be use changing color of placeholder value

Comment: @RusselMonzur: what exactly u want to do with css? explain briefly

Comment: Actually for styling reason in chrome placeholder was not shown and IE produce same problem but your answer solve my all problem .Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try **OnFocus** rather than using placeholder it will work

```
<input name="nom" type="text" value="Votre Nom" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
```

Let me know whether it works or not

Comment: I am new here . To upvote your answer i have to gain 15 reputation. But your answer is helpfull for me . When I gained 15 reputation I will upvote you . I need a help from you can give some effective link for developing responsive css design . I will be thanksfull to you if do this for me.

Comment: @RusselMonzur: Basically you should have some advance knowledge of HTML and CSS to learn Responsive css desgin. Anyways
Please see the link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp
http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/

Comment: @BN, Your solution above is working great, but is it possible that I can have different color for both the values?

I mean default color is red (for initial Value) and then a different color for inserted value?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have the right colours set up, and one on focus, and the focus one comes later (for higher specificity).  For instance:

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #888;
}
```